# How can an on-topic post be closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, off-topic, reopen-closed

Regarding the closure of this post: [How to know which version of QuickBooks (Pro/Premier/Enterprise) the user is using with IPP v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893472/)

I'm trying to understand how this can be seen as off-topic. SKG was asking how to accomplish a particular task within the Intuit QuickBooks API--most assuredly a programming topic.

Not only that, but it was closed by five people! How can that be? And no opportunity for discussion or appeal? Just slam, bang, off with your head.

I'm new to SO and I appreciate seniority, but this doesn't seem right. Some assistance and clarification about how this works will be appreciated. I looked at the FAQ and there's nothing there that would preclude SKG's question.

Comment: Often the voters misunderstand the question. This is especially an issue when the question is asked by non native english speakers. I often see people comment that the question is not clear enough when to me it is perfectly clear as demonstrated by my answer to the question and the fact that my answer was accepted by the asker - still sometimes the question was closed for not being clear (which is illogical since it has an accepted answer).

Comment: For what it's worth, once you gain enough points you can reopen questions that was closed by other user. That's what I do here often. Also remember - this is teh internets.

Comment: I'm wondering if [intuit-partner-platform] is something else and not an appropriate tag?  I'm not certain.

Comment: @coge.soft That's a good question...  I assume it was chosen by Intuit, so I don't know. FWIW, I feel SO was a poor choice by them to host their developer discussions. There are many questions relevant to their platform that need to be posted publicly for the benefit of all, yet aren't programming questions per se. I don't think Intuit considered this aspect in their decision.

Comment: I agree with the migration and I appreciate it, but who did it and how?

Comment: @InteXX Unless the migrator(s) speak up, there is no way to tell. Moderators can migrate a question and on some sites 5 users with 3k reputation can as well.

Comment: @Seth Ah, OK. Any possibility for some sort of appeal process for posts hastily closed as off-topic? The lack of due process is a bit troubling.

Comment: I'd say this is the appeal process.

Comment: @madth3 Yes, meta is *one of* the appeal processes. You can also custom flag the question asking a moderator to do it or (and) you can ask in chat for help. There definitely *is* an appeal process ;)

Comment: @InteXX, ok, the question is opened now.

Comment: Please note also: "Closed" is not an end-state. It is unfortunately named; perhaps it should be "Hold up. There's a possible problem here. Let's straighten it out."

Comment: @Intexx Intuit only moved technical discussions about the Intuit Partner Platform to Stack Overflow (REST APIs, Openid, Oauth etc. Non technical discussions are still here https://idnforums.intuit.com/, Intuit also has a huge Live community of customers to discuss customer facing topics http://community.intuit.com/

Comment: @AlEverett Ah, good point. I'm curious, is this a community-decided sort of thing?

Comment: @JarredKeneally Thanks for the links, those help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The likely reason has already been mentioned by sbletman in the comments.

Note that your question has now [been reopened](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15893472/revisions). Having multiple members of the community take part in an action is one way to cut down on errors, but they can still happen - which is why there is a `reopen` button visible to those with enough rep. Having said that, sometimes it can be a line call and it takes some further clarification of the question before it gets reopened - this is a good thing and generally leads to better question quality.

I don't necessarily want to second guess what the ♦ mods on SO want, but I would suggest you *don't* flag a closed question for moderator attention *except as a last resort*. If you have enough rep you can cast your own reopen vote. There is also a recent change whereby if an OP edits their closed question it automatically gets sent to the reopen review queue, which will potentially cut down on mistakenly closed questions staying closed (which results in questions like this on Meta).

Comment: That "pending change" has already been implemented. ;)

Comment: @animuson Cheers, I've edited accordingly.

Comment: I don't think flagging is a "last resort".. At least not on my site. I guess the mods on SO might not like it though since they have so many other flags to attend to.

Comment: My goodness... I'm impressed at the level of community involvement in all of this. I had no idea. Thanks, all  :-)